# Acute accent character eliminate using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to either eliminate or replace the acute accent character with a simple single quote character in xslt 1.0.This is what I have tried so far and none of them replace that character. What could be wrong with my translate construct?

`<xsl:value-of select="translate(HeaderFields/Name,'#xb4','')"/>`

`<xsl:value-of select="translate(HeaderFields/Name,'0xb4','')"/>`

`<xsl:value-of select="translate(HeaderFields/Name,'´','\'')"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select='translate(HeaderFields/Name,"&#xb4;","&apos;")'/>
```

Note the exchange of double and single quotation marks - see explanation at: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Introduction

Comment: "&#xb4;" does the trick. However,  &apos; is failing but &quot; works. What could be the reason?

Comment: The reason could be that you did not fully follow my advice. Or read the explanation I linked to.

Comment: My bad. Works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can express an acute accent as `'´'` or as `&#xb4;`. Neither `'#xb4'` nor `'0xb4'` is correct. (Were you just guessing?)

Expressing the single quote is a bit trickier. In XSLT 2.0 you can write it as `''''`, but that doesn't work in 1.0. In 1.0 the best way is to use a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="translate(HeaderFields/Name,'´',$apos)"/>
```

Finally, you need to be aware that an acute accent might not be a free-standing Unicode character; it might be combined with the character that it modifies, so for example `á` could be expressed as the single code point `xE1`. To ensure that it is a separate character you need to convert the text to decomposed normal form, which can be done in 2.0 using the normalize-unicode() function, but this is not available in 1.0.

Comment: "&#xb4;" does the trick. However,  with '´'  it fails out. Expressing the single quote as a variable works perfectly.

Comment: If  '´' fails that's probably because of an encoding problem. Does the stylesheet have an XML encoding declaration? Are you using an editor that's aware of the XML encoding?

Comment: Kindly tell me how to put the XML encoding declaration as I don't have it at the moment. Also, I am using notepad++.

Comment: The XML encoding declaration reads something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` and it can appear on stylesheets just like any other XML document. I don't use notepad++, but check what it has to say about file encodings for XML in particular.

Comment: I get a data such as ```<Name>O’Brien </Name>``` in a incoming XML.

Code point 0x92 (146 decimal) which is the right single quotation mark, or apostrophe (’) in Windows-1252 seems to be an invalid character in ISO 8859 and in UTF-8. Is it possible to replace this character with a simple &apos; using the translate function of xslt version="1.0" and if yes then what should be the value of from character?

I have tried with ```&#x92;``` but it does not work.

```<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>```
```<xsl:value-of select='translate(HeaderFields/Name,"&#x92;","&apos;")'/> ```

Comment: If the XML declaration says it's UTF-8 but it's actually Windows-1252 then you've got a horrible mess to sort out. Repairing the broken document is the easy part: the hard part is fixing your processes and workflow so it doesn't happen again.